# Memory leaks discovered in main.m

Tags: iphone

Following is my main.m

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    NSAutoreleasePool * pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
    int retVal = UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, nil);
    [pool release];
    return retVal;
}
```

Memory leaks discovered at the line

```
 int retVal = UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, nil);
```

How do I debug this?

Comment: Have you tried to use Instruments?

Answer (score 0):

if you are using xcode 4.0 or newer version then most of time you get error at this point so keep using instruments or watch you app at which point it crashs and then place breakpoint at that point and see what goings wrong.

and also try Analyze from product menu it gives you memory leaks errors.

Comment: I am using xcode 3.2.4. Can you tell more about analyse from product menu?

Comment: see this link https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#featuredarticles/StaticAnalysis/FeaturedArticle.html

Answer (score 0):

Number 1 rule in C/C++ or Objective-C if you have allocated memory YOU must free it by yourself. It's not Java or .NET where memory management is done automatically.

Please read: [Objective-c Memory Management For Lazy People](http://interfacelab.com/objective-c-memory-management-for-lazy-people/)

Or you can use autorelease:

```
[[[NSImage alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:@"/tmp/youownthis.jpg"] autorelease];
```

Comment: Or with Xcode 4 you could use ArC - or for OSX Snow Leopard or higher garbage collection to make this easier